# How to make a button press have different outputs depending on time pressed in Python?

Tags: python

I am attempting to learn how to program a little. I am making this script for my Raspberry Pi, but the concept doesn't have to be specifically for it. I want to have a button press that will execute one of two commands:

If held for one second, then run command A
If held for five seconds, then run command B
It is okay for command A to run multiple times while waiting for B to register.

Here is my script, and afterwards I will explain its purpose:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import uinput
inport time
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)

def main():
     events = (
          uinput.KEY_ESC,
          )

     device = uinput.Device(events)

     device.emit(uinput.KEY_ESC, 1) #Press
     device.emit(uinput.KEY_ESC, 0) #Release
```

Then, here are the two things that I want to have added:

```
while 1:

     if time.sleep(1)
     if GPIO.input(17)==True:
          main()
          break

while 1:

     if time.sleep(10)
     if GPIO.input(17)==True:
          os.system("sudo reboot")
          break
```

Essentially, this script will cause the button to have two purposes. Pressing it for one second will emulate a keystroke of the key ESC. Pressing it for ten seconds will cause it to reboot the system. How can I have the two happen at the same time? Learning Python is pretty challenging for me, but I've had no programming experience at all until now.

Answer (score 1):

Though, I don't have experience with with Raspberry Pi, I have decided to answer you, since it look like you have been missing attention, from guru. With corresponding with this article [Buttons and Switches](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/), I think follwed code should work properly:

```
import os
import time
while True:
    if GPIO.input(17):
    #start counting pressed time
    pressed_time=time.monotonic()
    while GPIO.input(17): #call: is button still pressed
        # just to force process wait
        # may be possible use in this time.sleep(1) but I don't have confidence
        pass
    pressed_time=time.monotonic()-pressed_time
    if pressed_time<5:
        #send corresponding signal, you mentioned to call "main()", ok then:
        main()
    elif pressed_time>=5:
        os.system("sudo reboot")
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not speak for your special case but in general when you want a button to be pressed and measure the time. Maybe it is of help.

The algorithm is in the comments and I sketch the Python equivalent:

```
import time
while 1:
    time.sleep(0.001) # do not use all the cpu power
    # make a loop to test for the button being pressed
    if button == pressed:
        when_pressed = time.time()
        while button == pressed:
            # wait until the button is not pressed any more
            time.sleep(0.001) # do not use all the cpu power
        # measure the time
        time_pressed = time.time() - when_pressed
        if time_pressed < too_short:
            continue # pressed too short do not use the other cases
        if 1 < time_pressed < 10:
            pass # pressed more than 1 second but less then 10
        if time_pressed > 10:
            pass # pressed more then 10 seconds 
            # a computer usually uses 6 seconds to wait for the shutdown
```

Comment: I have no ideea about RPi, but every UI toolkit have a „background” timer and a main waiting loop. I'll use that instead of time.sleep witch block the script.

Comment: Maybe you do not need a UI. You can run this script in the background from the start of the raspberry Pi. So you need a function that is called frequently and does not block?

Comment: That's something else and your answer will fit. But I bet you will work a lot to make buttons (that's wat OP asked) with state - pressed/not pressed - outside of some UI.

Comment: I just saw `GPIO` (hardware-pins) so I was guessing that the question was about a hardware-button. Also the shutdown behaviour.. equals much that of a hardware button on my laptop. But of cause you can create an answer that fits UIs well. Feel free to use this code.